# How much does ocean cover percentage change between glacial periods?

Tags: oceanography, earth-history, glaciology, sea-level, ice-age

Currently, oceans cover about 71% of the total area of Earth. Ice ages can cause this figure to fluctuate, by lowering the sea level and creating land bridges and other features.

How much can this figure fluctuate by? What were the most recent high and low points?